# How do I stop Lubuntu from asking my screen resolution every time I open the laptop lid?

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, suspend, laptop

Whenever I open my laptop, Lubuntu asks me for my screen resolution.

[image]

I've picked Save, Apply, and Cancel, but it comes up every time I open the laptop. How do I make it stop and stick with the current resolution?

Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS